# How to rotate a SCNNode by multiple angles?

Tags: rotation, swiftui, scenekit

I am having a cylinder as a `SCNCylinder` in a `SCNView`. I want to rotate the cylinder by a number of given angles. I am using SwiftUI to give the required input (angle of rotation). Suppose I give it a input as 90° . Currently it can easily rotate by 90°, but if I give it a second input of 180°, it goes back to its original position and then it rotates by 180°. I want it to rotate by 180° from the position it got after its 90° rotation.

Here is my code :

```
struct ContentView: View {
 @State var rotationAngle: Float = 0
 var body: some View {

    VStack{

        Text("180°").onTapGesture {
            self.rotationAngle = 180.0
        }

        Divider()

        Text("90°").onTapGesture {
            self.rotationAngle = 90.0
        }

        SceneKitView(angle: $rotationAngle)
            .position(x: 225.0, y: 175)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)

    }
  }    
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @Binding var angle: Float


func degreesToRadians(_ degrees: Float) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(degrees * .pi / 180)
}

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.allowsCameraControl = true
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    sceneView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 10, width: 0, height: 1)

    return sceneView
}

func updateUIView(_ sceneView: SCNView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) {

        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
            node.removeFromParentNode() }


        let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: 0.02, height: 2.0)
        let cylindernode = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)
        cylindernode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0)
        cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green


        cylindernode.pivot = SCNMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, -1, 0)




        let rotation = SCNAction.rotate(by: self.degreesToRadians(self.angle),
                                        around: SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), duration: 5)



         cylindernode.runAction(rotation)


        sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(cylindernode)

   }
```

I wish it to rotate properly no matter how many angles I give it.

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, you want the cylinder to continue rotating from it's current position every time the button is pressed *not* have the cylinder go to a fixed either 90 or 180 position.

Because your current code seems to be setup to do the second thing (except for the `rotate:by`). The rotationAngle is held as a fixed state. Really you should be sending rotate commands to the node without keeping the amount it rotated around in a state variable.

But, working with the code you have now:

Inside the `updateUIView` stick to only doing updates to your nodes. Right now, you are tearing down and recreating the entire node hierarchy to it's original position every time `rotationAngle` changes. That's probably why thing are redrawing.
Instead do that setup inside `makeUIView` or inside an initializer for `SceneKitView` and in `updateUIView` just apply the new rotation.

Second problem is that when you set `rotationAngle` by pressing the button to say 180, if you press the same button again, the value is set again to 180. The value hasn't changed so as far as SwiftUI is concerned, there is no need to call `updateUIView`. There's a couple ways to make it update, but a quick and easy way is probably just rotate by 0 then immediately after by the angle you want.
*But* again you really should not hold that angle in a state variable. Better to just make a `rotateCylinder(angle: Angle)` function in `SceneKitView` and call it from the button.

Also, why not use the new `Angle` type? Here's your code with some of those changes. I think this what you are trying to do, but I could be wrong.

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import SceneKit

struct ContentView: View {

  @State var rotationAngle: Angle = .zero

  var body: some View {

    VStack{

      HStack {

        Spacer()
        Text("180°").onTapGesture {
          self.rotationAngle = .zero
          self.rotationAngle = .degrees(180)
        }
        Spacer()

        Divider()

        Spacer()
        Text("90°").onTapGesture {
          self.rotationAngle = .zero
          self.rotationAngle = .degrees(90)
        }
        Spacer()

        }.frame(height: 100).padding()

      SceneKitView(radius: 0.2, height: 2, angle: $rotationAngle)

    }
  }
}

struct SceneKitView: UIViewRepresentable {

  @Binding var angle: Angle

  let node: SCNNode

  init(radius: CGFloat, height: CGFloat, angle: Binding<Angle>) {

    let cylinder = SCNCylinder(radius: radius, height: height)
    cylinder.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
    self.node = SCNNode(geometry: cylinder)

    self._angle = angle
  }

  func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) -> SCNView {

    let sceneView = SCNView()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
    sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(node)

    return sceneView
  }

  func updateUIView(_ sceneView: SCNView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SceneKitView>) {
    print("Updating view \(angle.degrees)")

    // To continue rotating
    let rotation = SCNAction.rotate(by: CGFloat(angle.radians), around: SCNVector3(1, 0, 0), duration: 3)

    // To go to a fixed angle state
    //let rotation = SCNAction.rotate(toAxisAngle: SCNVector4(1, 0, 0, angle.radians), duration: 3)

    node.runAction(rotation)

  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your solution really works. I just wanted to ask you a slightly different variant of this question. I want to rotate each of the angles (180° and 90°) around two different axes, say 180° around SCNVector( 1, 0, 0 ) and 90° around( 0, 0, 1 ). I am really struggling to find way around this. Is there a way to way the same ?

Comment: If you just want the pivot around to be  (1, 0, 0) if angle is 180, you can just have an if statement in updateUIView and check if 180 or 90 or something else.  Now, if you want another variable that is pivot, it is not as straight forward as it seems. You can make another state variable for it (this time it should be a state). But, the view will updated when the pivot changes. Which I don't think is what you want. You would have to make the whole view conform to `Equatable` to only update if angle changes and not pivot.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solution works. But the whole thing just crashes when I use `self.rotationAngle = .zero`. Not sure why this happens. It runs but it does not update the view when I remove it.

Comment: The code is the same as you recommend to me. If you run this in playground, I get the error "There was a problem encountered while running this playground. Please check your code for error."

Comment: If you get an error like that while trying to run something in a playground, try it in a project and see what happens.